# White spot on my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a random website but & my problem is that there's this white spot on top of the page that's also interfering with how the background is supposed to look.  Why's this happening?  I cannot find anything that's causing this happen.  Below the code is as follows.  JS > CSS > HTML.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

JS > CSS > HTML is how

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".pull-me").click(function() {
                $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".pull-me2").click(function() {
                $(".panel2").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
            html {
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                background-image: url("http://i64.tinypic.com/2jdn8lw.jpg");
            }

            #mainHeader {
                text-shadow: -14px 3px 10px;
                font-size: 85px;
                font-family: cursive;
            }

            .1 {
                height: 10px;
            }

            .panel {
                text-align: center;
                display: none;
            }   

            .panel2 {
                text-align: center;
                display: none;
            }   

            .pull-me {  
                text-align: center;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 30px;
                color: black;
            }

            .pull-me2 { 
                text-align: center;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 30px;
            }

            .pull-me3 { 
                text-align: center;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 30px;
            }

            #ig {
                height: 30px;
            }

            .menu {
                 -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                background-image: url("http://i64.tinypic.com/2hozok4.jp");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                font-family: cursive;
                width: -500px;
            }

        </style>
```

```html
 <header>
        <h1 class="text-center" id="mainHeader">Random Website</h1>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/piccolo_villagio/" ><img id="ig" src="http://www.logosurfer.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/instagram-logo_0.png?itok=ujucvqfJ" height = "20px"></a>

            <div class="panel">
                <img class="1 img-responsive" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/scrp6h.jpg" width="324"></a>
                <h3>500</h3>
                    <img class="1 img-responsive" src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2h7qbn4.jpg" width="324"></a>
                        <br/>
                <br/>  
                    </div>
                        <div class="pull-me">Scroll Menu 1</div>
        </header>
        <!--
        Entering body below
        -->
        <body>
            <div class="panel2">
                    <div class="menu">
    
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-me2">Scroll Menu 2</div>
    </body>
```

[Screenshot of HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mEbk.jpg)

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot because it is not recognizable from the snippet.

Comment: Hey Kaan,  I uploaded a screenshot on the bottom of my post.

Comment: where is the white spot?

Comment: You don't see it?  It's right in the middle of "Random Website" and "Scroll Menu 1" and "Scroll Menu 2".

Comment: Everything looks okay here: https://jsfiddle.net/oj91Lb1d/

Comment: Click on where it says, Screenshot of HTML page on the bottom of my post.

Comment: What do you mean by white spot? The entire background of that section in the screenshot is white. Can you be more specific? Are you talking about the gap at the top of the page above "Random Website"?

Comment: Yeah that both parts!  That entire section shouldn't be white.  Why's that happening?

Comment: What should it be?

Comment: It should just be the entire background showing up without any section containing a white spot.

Comment: One other question: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: I have found some syntactical mistakes in your code and resolved them. Here is the updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/oj91Lb1d/1/ and still there is no white background

Comment: Yeah, I am using bootstrap

Comment: Out of curiosity, what syntactical mistakes did I make?

Comment: You have margin: 8px on the body. That should not be there. It should be padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is white because of the **bootstrap.css**.

Just comment out the `background-color: #fff` line in **scaffolding.less** file

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    /* background-color: #fff; */
}
```

or you can add the code below to your .css file

```
body {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

Here is the updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/oj91Lb1d/2/

By the way, `<header>` tags should be inside the `<body>` tags. Most probably, you confused it with the `<head>` tags. Besides that, there are two `</a>` tags, which supposed to include the `<img/>` tags but there were no opening `<a href="#">` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could check again moving your `<body>` tag up, since you are using it after the `<header>` tag. `<body>` should wrap everything on the html part.